# I need to add new custom ROLE in a symfony 2 to manage the permission in the SONATA Bundle

Tags: security, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata-user-bundle

I need to create a new ROLE as ROLE_ERECTA_TASK_ADMIN but I don't know how, where I must to declare to se it in a Sonata admin interface?
I use Sonata Bundle to manage my User Group Role, now I have only some ROLES but I want to create some other form my Bundles.

My security.yml

```
role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_USER, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN]
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
        # PROTEZIONE MODULO TASK
        ROLE_ERECTA_TASK_ADMIN: [ROLE_ERECTA_TASK_USER]
        ROLE_ERECTA_TASK_SA: [ROLE_ERECTA_TASK_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
        SONATA:
            - ROLE_SONATA_PAGE_ADMIN_PAGE_EDIT  # if you are using acl then this line must be commented
```

Sonata Admin User manager:
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another quick workaround to add roles. Just edit `security.yml` and add roles to ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN.

```
role_hierarchy:
    ...
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH, ROLE_FOO, ROLE_BAR, ...]
```

Comment: Thanks, I can add under ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN and ROLE_ADMIN my new Roles, This not change any Sonata file so is very clean. For new version of my software I will try to setting my roles in this way.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to set up the roles manually in the formMapper like that :

```
$formMapper->with('Roles')
                ->add('roles', 'choice',
                    array('choices'=>
                    array('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN' => 'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN', 'ROLE_...' => 'ROLE_...'),
                        'expanded'=> true,
                        'multiple'=> true))
                ->end();
```

Also add `ROLE_ADMIN` and `ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN` to your roles.

Answer (score 0):

for a more flexible implementation one can also override vendor/sonata-project/user-bundle/Security/EditableRolesBuilder.php.

Do not edit this file directly, but do this through bundle inheritance or override the service sonata.user.editable_role_builder to inject a custom class.

Answer (score 0):

I do have some customized action within my Admin classes. What I do is, just "configuring" these within the admin classes. The standard Sonata\UserBundle\Security\EditableRolesBuilder calls the public function of the Sonata BaseAdmin class "getSecurityInformation":

```
foreach ($admin->getSecurityInformation() as $role => $permissions) {
$role = sprintf($baseRole, $role);
if ($isMaster) {
    // if the user has the MASTER permission, allow to grant access the admin roles to other users
    $roles[$role] = $role;
} elseif ($this->securityContext->isGranted($role)) {
    // although the user has no MASTER permission, allow the currently logged in user to view the role
    $rolesReadOnly[$role] = $role;
}
```

}

That's where I hook in. Just overwrite this function own Admin class (I have done this in my BaseAdmin class which extends from Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin)

```
/**
 * List here the customized roles actions which are used within the Admin class you have extended. (e.g. the
 * CustomerAdmin uses a special function to login as the customer. In this case set the array to array('LOGIN') and
 * use at certain points like ->isGranted('LOGIN'). This is also available in templates like
 * admin.isGranted('LOGIN', object)).
 * The actions you are listing here, will be appended to the standard actions: EDIT, LIST, CREATE, VIEW, DELETE,
 * EXPORT, OPERATOR, MASTER.
 *
 * @see http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/index.html
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $customizedRoles = array();

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getSecurityInformation()
{
    $standardAdminRoles = parent::getSecurityInformation();
    $customizedAdminRoles = $this->getCustomizedAdminRoles();

    $allAdminRoles = array_merge($standardAdminRoles, $customizedAdminRoles);
    ksort($allAdminRoles);

    return $allAdminRoles;
}

/**
 * Get the customized roles set at property of the Admin class 'customizedRoles' prepared to append to the standard
 * roles.
 *
 * @return array
 */
private function getCustomizedAdminRoles()
{
    $customizedRoles = array();

    if (is_array($this->customizedRoles) && !empty($this->customizedRoles)) {
        foreach ($this->customizedRoles as $customizedRole) {
            $customizedRole = strtoupper($customizedRole);
            $customizedRoles[$customizedRole] = $customizedRole;
        }
    }

    return $customizedRoles;
}
```

And the just fill this array in your Admin class by overwriting:

```
/** @{inheritdoc} */
protected $customizedRoles = array('LOGIN');
```

That's it. Effort and design seems to be pretty fair for me. :-)

Answer (score -2):

I have found another way, thanks to Rpg600 :)

I wrote this code on vendor/bundles/Sonata/UserBundle/Form/Type/SecurityRolesType.php

public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
{
    $options = parent::getDefaultOptions($options);

```
$roles = array();
//== MY-CODE ============================================================================================================
$Role_to_add= array();
foreach ($this->pool->getContainer()->getParameter('security.role_hierarchy.roles') as $key => $value_roles_group_array)
    if('_ALL'== substr($key,-4,4))
            foreach ($value_roles_group_array as $key => $new_roles_string)
                $roles[$new_roles_string]=$new_roles_string;
//======================================================================================================================                
$rolesReadOnly = array();

...
```

Now in app/config/security.yml

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_USER, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN]
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
    # PROTEZIONE MODULO TASK
    ROLE_ERECTA_TASK_ALL: [ROLE_ERECTA_TASK_USER, ROLE_ERECTA_TASK_ADMIN, ROLE_ERECTA_TASK_SA]
    ROLE_ERECTA_TASK_ADMIN: [ROLE_ERECTA_TASK_USER]
    ROLE_ERECTA_TASK_SA: [ROLE_ERECTA_TASK_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
    SONATA:
        - ROLE_SONATA_PAGE_ADMIN_PAGE_EDIT  # if you are using acl then this line must be commented
```

When I add in the hierarchy role a ROLE ended by "_ALL" my code load all sub element inside showing the new role string in the sonata admin form user.

[image: Sonata Form Admin with the roles added by my code]

Now when I perform the login I can See my new Roles.

[image: Symfony System account info]

Comment: Extremely bad idea to edit anything under the vendor directory.

Comment: Yeah, that's the absolute last thing you want to do, if ever at all